# Annihilator norm has a minimizer?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be Banach and $U$ a subspace. Then consider the forward annihilator $$U^{\perp}= \left\{ f \in X': f(u)=0 \ \forall u \in U \right\}$$

where $X'$ is the dual space.
Is it true that for any $f \in X'$ there is $g \in U^{\perp}$ such that

$$\inf_{u \in U^{\perp}}\left\lVert u-f \right\rVert= \left\lVert u-g \right\rVert?$$

I only know that such minimizers can be found in Hilbert spaces and on compact spaces. I am not sure about this annihilator space, though.

Comment: Is $X'$ the space of bounded linear functionals?

Comment: that's right, it is the dual space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove this with Hahn-Banach. Fix some arbitrary $f\in X'$, which we can assume isn't in $U^\perp$. For any $u\in U^\perp$ we have
\begin{align*}
\|f-u\|&=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)-u(x)| \\
&\geq \sup_{\substack{\|x\|\leq 1 \\ x\in U}}|f(x)-u(x)|\\
& = \sup_{\substack{\|x\|\leq 1 \\ x\in U}}|f(x)|\\
&=\|f|_U\|_U.
\end{align*}
This implies that $d(f,U^{\perp})\geq \|f\|_U$. Let us consider the restriction $f|_U$ of $f$ to $U$. Define $F$ to be the Hahn-Banach extension of $f|_U$ (so $F\in X^*$ again). We are guaranteed that $\|F\|=\|f|_U\|_U$. On $U$ we have that $g:=f-F=0$. Hence $g\in U^\perp$, and $\|f-g\|=\|f|_U\|$. Thus the distance between $f$ and $U^\perp$ is minimized by $g$.